# Android: Carrying EditText over to new intent and inserting into TextView

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to make it so that once the user enters there name into the given EditText then accesses guessing game from the main menu it redirects you to new Activity in this case the Guessing game but it will not carry over the Information To TextView.

Here is my Code for GameMenu.java:

```
public class GameMenu extends Activity {




private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;


    // TextViews
    TextView Help;

    // String's
    String GameSelec;

    //Intent
    Intent Intent;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gamemenu);
        Help = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextHelp);
        Help.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }




    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menuoptions, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.help:
            Help = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextHelp);
            Help.setText("Enter your name and Select game to play");
            Help.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Handler handle = new Handler();
            handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Help.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }, 10000);
            return true;
             case R.id.GuesGame:
             Toast.makeText(this, "Redirecting Now",
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             Intent myIntent = new Intent(GameMenu.this, GuessGame.class);

             EditText EditName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditName);
             myIntent.putExtra("Name", EditName.getText().toString());

             startActivityForResult(myIntent, REQUEST_CODE);

             return true;
             case R.id.Game2:
             Toast.makeText(this, "In Development",
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             return true;
             case R.id.Game3:
                 Toast.makeText(this, "In Development",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Then this is my gamemenu.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".GameMenu" >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:rowCount="14"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Gamemenu"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="Game Menu: Follow Instructions"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/GameInsruct"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:text="Please enter name and select game"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditName"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Your name here"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextMessage"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_row="13"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextHelp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_row="13"
            android:text="Help"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then GuessGame.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;


public class GuessGame extends Activity {


    // TextViews
    TextView Welcome;
    TextView Txtname;
    TextView Txtnumber;

    // EditViews
    EditText EdtName;
    EditText EditNum1;
    EditText EditNum2;
    EditText EditGuess;

    // Buttons
    Button BtnDisp;

    // RadioGroup-Related
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private RadioButton easy, medium, hard;

    // int's
    int Max;
    int max;
    int random;
    int Attempts;
    int guess;
    int num1;


    // Strings
    String name;
    String result;
    String Strngnum1;
    String NameExtra;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);




        Intent Intent = getIntent();

        if (Intent.hasExtra(NameExtra)){
        TextView setName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EdtName);
        String NameExtra = Intent.getStringExtra("Player");
        setName.setText("Player:" + NameExtra + "Have Fun");
        }


        //name = NameExtra;

        /*Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras !=null) {
            NameExtra = extras.getString("Name");

        if (NameExtra != null) {
            TextView setName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EditName);
            setName.setText("Player:" + NameExtra + "Have Fun");
            name = NameExtra;



        }


        }
            */  

                /*
                 */

        Attempts = Attempts + 3;

        //EditName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EdtName);
        EditNum1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EdtNum1);
        Txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UserDisp);

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // find which radio button is selected
                if (checkedId == R.id.Easy) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choice: 1-5",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (checkedId == R.id.Medium) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choice: 1-10",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (checkedId == R.id.Hard) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choice: 1-20",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }

        });

        easy = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Easy);
        medium = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Medium);
        hard = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Hard);

    }

    public void Start(View StartDisp) {

        int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();


        //Txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UserDisp);
        //Txtname.setText(name);

        // find which radio Button is checked by id
        if (selectedId == easy.getId()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Chose 'Easy' '1-5'",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(
                    Color.parseColor("#abf234"));
            max = 5;
        } else if (selectedId == medium.getId()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "You Chose 'Medium' '1-10'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(
                    Color.parseColor("#E8A317"));
            max = 10;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Chose 'Hard' '1-20'",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(
                    Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
            max = 20;

        }

        random = RandomNumber(max);

        //Txtname.setText(name + random );




        Txtname = new TextView(this);
        Txtnumber = new TextView(this);
        TextView DispInform = new TextView(this);


        EdtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EdtName);
        EditNum1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EdtNum1);
        Txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UserDisp);

        Txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EditName);
        Txtname.setText(name);
        Txtnumber =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.EdtNum1);
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(Txtnumber.getText().toString());
        Strngnum1 = String.valueOf(num1);



        StringBuilder StrngBuild = new StringBuilder();
        StrngBuild.append(name);
        StrngBuild.append(" You have Chosen the number");
        StrngBuild.append(Strngnum1);
    line 181    StrngBuild.append(random);
        DispInform = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DispAll);
        DispInform.setText(StrngBuild);



    }

    public void Guess(View BtnGuess) {

        TextView tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

        if (Attempts > 0) {

            EditGuess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EdtGuess);
            guess = Integer.parseInt(EditGuess.getText().toString());

            if (guess == random) {
                result = "Correct";
                tvResult.setText(result);
                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(
                        Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

            }

            else if ((guess + 3 == random) || (guess - 3 == random)) {
                Attempts = Attempts - 1;
                result = "Almost There";
                tvResult.setText(result);
            }

            else if (guess - 6 == random) {
                Attempts = Attempts - 1;
                result = "Sky High that one";
                tvResult.setText(result);
            }

            else if (guess + 6 == random) {
                Attempts = Attempts - 1;
                result = "Low blow guess that one";
                tvResult.setText(result);
            }
            else
            {
                Attempts = Attempts - 1;
            }

        } else if (Attempts == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Out Of Attempts",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(
                    Color.parseColor("#43C6DB"));
        }

    }

    public int RandomNumber(int Max) {

        int random = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((Max - 1) - 1));

        return random;

    }

    /*
     * public void generateRandom() { random =
     * Min+(int)(Math.random()*((Max-Min) + 1));
     * 
     * if(random > Max || random < Min) { generateRandom(); }
     * 
     * }
     */

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gamemain, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

game.xml:

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Welcome"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="Welcome:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EntrNum"
        android:layout_width="167dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:text="Please enter a number between 1 - 20"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EdtName"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:text="" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EdtNum1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/sound" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Easy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1-5" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1-10" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Hard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1-20" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EdtGuess"
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="15"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Take A Guess"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/StartDisp"
        android:layout_width="164dp"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="14"
        android:onClick="Start"
        android:text="Start Game" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnGuess"
        android:layout_width="131dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_row="17"
        android:onClick="Guess"
        android:text="Guess" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="226dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="7" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="9" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="10" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="11" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="12" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="13" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="15" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="219dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="17" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="14" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="77dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="4" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="4" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="4" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="162dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="4" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="196dp"
        android:layout_row="4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="16"
        android:text="result" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DispAll"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnReturn"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_row="17"
        android:text="Return To Home Screen" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/UserDisp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</GridLayout>
```

It would be very helpful and much appreciated if you can help my solve this problem also another issue is whenever i am on the GuessingGame and attempt to start my app crashes and this is the LogCat Error window from it:

```
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397): Process: com.Lewis.c3383583task3, PID: 1397
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     ... 11 more
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.Lewis.c3383583task3.GuessGame.Start(GuessGame.java:181)
03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     ... 14 more
```

if you see anything that you think could be an issue please tell me thanks.

Comment: What is line no 181 in GuessGame.java?

Comment: Line 181 is part of a string builder

Comment: which line is that exactly?

Comment: i'll update code where line 181 is

Comment: There if you Scroll down on GuessGame.java you will see line 181

Comment: Ok..Try to Toast the value of random after the line `random = RandomNumber(max);` ..and if you get any error , show me the logcat..

Comment: I think `RandomNumber(max)` is returning null and thus random is also null.

Comment: Tried that and errors are same

Comment: Ok on which line is the new error???

Comment: random works fine as the GuessingGame code works fine without passing information but i need this intent added onto it for an assignment

Comment: Ok but on which line is the new error?

Comment: There isnt a new error it gives identical log cat as one posted

Comment: Check the logcat for the error like 03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 03-15 14:48:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.Lewis.c3383583task3.GuessGame.Start(GuessGame.java:181)  and tell me the line no specified like 181

Comment: its still 181 and ive now commented out the StringBuild which is at that location